# Trying to edit Live Meeting Recording

Tags: recording, wmv, live-meeting

I've converted a Live Meeting to a .wmv file and am now trying to edit it. 
We added a few seconds of audio to the beginning of the recording and now the slides are out of sync.

How do I add a few second delay before the slides begin?

Or what file stores the presentation in the Live Meeting recording. Do i need to edit that first before converting to .wmv?

Answer (score 0):

You could import that to any video editing software and it will separate the audio and video tracks for you. Then you just need to clip the beginning a little bit and line up the audio again.

I can't recommend any software per say (Windows Movie Maker won't split the audio I don't think) but I use kdenlive in a Linux environment.

Answer (score 0):

Adobe Premiere can be used for such tasks, its a quality piece of video creating/converting/editing that we use at work for our PR clips. I'd highly recommend it, but its important to know that it is an enterprise-level piece of software. Well worth it in my opinion to complete these types of tasks